# jQuery-UI Select-Menu Widget CSS Customisation

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I seem to be having some difficulty setting CSS settings for jQuery-UI widgets, namely the SelectMenu. Simple properties such as margins are not working, and I can't find a way to set different CSS properties for two separate SelectMenu widgets. Here's a simplified extract of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JQuery Select Option</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#currency_selector").selectmenu();
      $("#currency_selector2").selectmenu();
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    label {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .ui-widget {
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .ui-selectmenu-open {
      max-height: 180px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .fieldSpace {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <label for="currency_selector">Currency:</label><br>
    <select id="currency_selector" class="fieldSpace"><br>
      <option disabled>Popular Currencies</option>
      <option value="EUR">Euro (€)</option>
      <option value="USD">US Dollar ($)</option>
      <option value="GBP">UK Pound Sterling (£)</option>            
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label for="currency_selector2">Currency:</label><br>
    <select id="currency_selector2" class="fieldSpace"><br>
      <option disabled>Asian Currencies</option>
      <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar ($)</option>
      <option value="MYR">Malaysian Rinngit (RM)</option>
      <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah (R)</option>            
    </select>        
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

1. Is there a way to set different background colors for the two selectors?
2. Is there a way to hide the scroll bars?
3. Why is it ignoring the fieldSpace class that sets the margins?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For theming like you want, consider using `classes` option to append custom classes to specific elements.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#currency_selector").selectmenu({
    classes: {
      "ui-selectmenu-button": "fieldSpace bg-white"
    }
  });
  $("#currency_selector2").selectmenu({
    classes: {
      "ui-selectmenu-button": "fieldSpace bg-blue"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

span.ui-selectmenu-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 101px;
}

div.ui-selectmenu-menu[class^='bg'].ui-selectmenu-open {
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

span[id^='currency_selector'].fieldSpace {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

span.bg-white {
  background: white;
}

span.bg-blue {
  background: #eef;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <label for="currency_selector">Currency:</label><br>
  <select id="currency_selector" class="fieldSpace"><br>
    <option disabled>Popular Currencies</option>
    <option value="EUR">Euro (€)</option>
    <option value="USD">US Dollar ($)</option>
    <option value="GBP">UK Pound Sterling (£)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <label for="currency_selector2">Currency:</label><br>
  <select id="currency_selector2" class="fieldSpace"><br>
    <option disabled>Asian Currencies</option>
    <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar ($)</option>
    <option value="MYR">Malaysian Rinngit (RM)</option>
    <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah (R)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Then it is a matter of using more specific CSS to ensure the proper properties are assigned.

Since this widget hides the `select` element, you may use absolute positing to get it to render as needed, as pseudo inline element.